# How to add quotes or a comma to strings in a RDD?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

How to add quotes or a comma to a string in a Scala RDD? I have a RDD that has one line of string from a text file with no quotes.  I have this scala code that gets me the line of text from the file:

```
val textFile = sc.textFile("ISS_LOG_FILE.TXT")

val newRDD = textFile.filter(line => line.contains(“56.34.2.299”)
```

I am looking to add a quote, like “, at the start and end of the line of text in the RDD.  So, it would be like:

> “Administrators need to start the server with the IP address of
>   56.34.2.299.”

How do I append a character like a quote to string inside a RDD?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can format with triple quotes:

```
map(line => s""""$line"""")
```

or concatenate with escaped quotes

```
map(line => "\"" + line +  "\"")
```